# document.getElementById(); does not work for third time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Determine Minheight and put it via javascript. It work successfully twice but same code is not working in third calling. This one (document.getElementById("rightadmin").style.minHeight=wrapHeight+'px';) is not working. More amazing is that if I make the 3rd one elevate to 2nd position then it works and then 3rd one not working. So basically whatever I put after 2nd one don't work.

JavaScript:

```
function height(){
var dheight= ($(document).height());
var wheight= ($(window).height());
if(dheight>wheight){ 
var wrapHeight= dheight;
}
else {

var wrapHeight=wheight; 
}
document.getElementById("iframeArea").style.minHeight=wrapHeight+'px';
document.getElementById("dailySchedule").style.minHeight=wrapHeight+'px';
document.getElementById("rightadmin").style.minHeight=wrapHeight+'px';
}
```

html:

```
<body onload="height();">
   <!--Start of iframeArea-->
   <div class="iframeArea" id="iframeArea">
      <div class="btnRight" id="rightadmin">

      </div>
     <!--End of btnRight-->
  </div>
<!--End of iframeArea-->
```

Comment: does element `dailySchedule` exist?

Comment: please provide the complete HTML structure,

Comment: try inspecting the HTML DOM with firefox -> firebug

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the `dailySchedule` id exists ? If not your function will throw an error and won't execute the last line.

Comment: yes. It exist. That class for another page and it works perfectly in its 2nd position. But if I put it in 3rd position and put the "rightadmin" at 2nd position then "dailySchedule" stop working and "rightadmin" start working.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Might be due to scope problems - the variable `wrapHeight` is local in two blocks.</strike>

Should not have any effect on the outcome, but this code is more elegant way to assign the third variable:

```
var dheight = $(document).height();
var wheight = $(window).height();
var wrapHeight = (dheight > wheight) ? dheight : wheight;
```

As all others already said, something else is the problem.

Comment: That's not how JavaScript works - blocks do not scope variables, only functions do.

Comment: @Pointy you're right, [should have checked it](http://jsfiddle.net/WWcnL/) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see element with id=**dailySchedule** on the page. If no element with that id is on the page you should get an error. Check browser console for javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

you say `<body onload='height()'>` and never check if the document is ready, and then there is perhaps no div with id rightadmin...
Try to convert to jQuery and do something like this and delete the onload attribute.

$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here

}

Comment: If you look at the html code you will see that "rightAdmin" is the id of 3rd block.

Comment: yes, i saw, but I say that if the document has not yet finished loading, there may not be a div with the id rightadmin YET! Because onload gets called during the loading of the webpage, so the page can be incomplete then. Isn't there something like onready? Because I think it will work he you replace onload with onready.

Answer (score 0):

I am using now the following code. It works fine for everything.

```
$(function(){   
  var dheight= ($(document).height());
  var wheight= ($(window).height());
  var wrapHeight = (dheight > wheight) ? dheight : wheight;
  $('.dailySchedule').css({ "min-height": wrapHeight + 'px' });
  $('.iframeArea').css({ "min-height": wrapHeight + 'px' });
 $('.btnRight').css({ "min-height": wrapHeight + 'px' });

});
```

Thanks for answeri